# Getting std class value without using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, object

First I thank all who read this post.
And here is the question.
I am trying to get category_id from this two std class that is under this categories array and add them into another array like

```
$categories = array(75,65);
```

Is there anyway that I can get them without using foreach?
It is already in a foreach and I need this category to proceed next step.

```
[categories] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_category_id] => 83125
            [category_id] => 75
            [product_id] => 10836
            [ordering] => 2
            [category_parent_id] => 51
            [category_type] => product
            [category_name] => Men boxer
            [category_description] => 
            [category_published] => 1
            [category_ordering] => 3
            [category_left] => 34
            [category_right] => 35
            [category_depth] => 5
            [category_namekey] => product_1494167920_122781373
            [category_created] => 1494167920
            [category_modified] => 1502169524
            [category_access] => all
            [category_menu] => 0
            [category_keywords] => men swimsuit, men swimming pants, swimsuit, men swimming suit, long sleeve swimming suit
            [category_meta_description] => Buy men swimming suit at xxxxx, men long sleeve swimsuit and swimming boxer available, Buy 2 FREE shipping
            [category_layout] => 
            [category_page_title] => Men Swim Boxer - xxxxx
            [category_alias] => men-boxer
            [category_site_id] => 
            [category_canonical] => 
            [category_quantity_layout] => 
            [hasbought] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_category_id] => 83124
            [category_id] => 65
            [product_id] => 10836
            [ordering] => 43
            [category_parent_id] => 43
            [category_type] => product
            [category_name] => Accessory
            [category_description] => 
            [category_published] => 1
            [category_ordering] => 5
            [category_left] => 87
            [category_right] => 114
            [category_depth] => 4
            [category_namekey] => product_1476761078_750345878
            [category_created] => 1476761078
            [category_modified] => 1502169605
            [category_access] => all
            [category_menu] => 0
            [category_keywords] => accessory, beach accessory, swimming accessory, xxxx
            [category_meta_description] => Shop accessory at xxxx, beach accessory, fashion accessory, gym accessory and many more, Free shipping & speed delivery
            [category_layout] => 
            [category_page_title] => Accessory - xxxxxxx
            [category_alias] => accessory
            [category_site_id] => 
            [category_canonical] => 
            [category_quantity_layout] => 
            [hasbought] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use another foreach inside the foreach?

Comment: @Geshode I afraid it will drag the processing speed.

Comment: Maybe try it out and see, if it considerably lowers the speed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` with a callback function. Without knowing more about your code, I could presume you could try something like this:

```
  function get_category_id($category) {
    return $category['category_id'];
  }
  $category_id = array_map('get_category_id', $categories);
```

You might also investigate `call_user_func_array` if you have an array of arrays to map through. I'm still learning PHP myself, but I think this should help

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, this is a job for array_reduce. Each iteration adds to the array as it goes.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

```
<?php
$data = makeSomeData();

$categories = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item){
    $carry[] = $item->category_id;
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($categories);
echo "\n";


function makeSomeData() {
    $input = [65, 165, 265, 365];
    $data = [];
    foreach($input as $id) {
        $a = new stdClass;
        $a->category_id = $id;
        $data[] = $a;        
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the foreach you referred for array or object inside, but for your case, simply do this

```
$catesTmp[] = array_map( function($item){ 
    return !empty($item->category_id) ? $item->category_id : null;
}, $categories );
```

It will return results you need.